# Setting request body for Guzzle 6 put()

Tags: put, guzzle6

I am setting the request body incorrectly for these Guzzle put() calls.  I am making get() calls to same API using same token without issue.

The API has a test environment and here is what a successful put call looks like in cURL:

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic tokenishere=' -d '{ \ 
   "OrganizationCode": "10", \ 
   "EventID": 5524, \ 
   "FunctionID": 321, \ 
   "Description": "Test" \ 
 }' 'https://example.com/api/v1/Functions/10/5524/321'
```

My Guzzle code is

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array("base_uri" => "https://example.com"));

$response = $client->put("/api/v1/Functions/10/".$_SESSION['eventID'].'/'.$functionID, 
    array(
        'headers'   => array(
            'token' => $token,  
            'debug' => true,            
        ), 
        'body' => $data
    )
```

I have also tried

```
$request = $client->put("/api/v1/Functions/10/$_SESSION[eventID]/$functionID", array('headers' => array('token' => $token)));
$request->setBody($data);
$response = $request->send();
```

And I have tried using param name json instead of body.

I have verified the JSON string in $data.

https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/request.html shows an example where the body is 3rd arg:

`$request = $client->put('http://httpbin.org/put', array(), 'this is the body');`

So I also tried this below but same issue...

```
$request = $client->put("/api/v1/Functions/10/".$_SESSION['eventID'].'/'.$functionID, array(
                        'headers'   => array(
                            'token' => $token,  
                            'debug' => true,            
                        )), $data);
```

Debug output is

```
PUT /api/v1/Functions/10/5524/321 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.52.1 PHP/7.3.6-1+0~20190531112735.39+stretch~1.gbp6131b7
Host: example.com
token: tokenisreallyhere==
debug: 1

{"OrganizationCode":10,"EventID":"5524","FunctionID":"321","Description":"Test"}PUT /api/v1/Functions/10/5524/321 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.52.1 PHP/7.3.6-1+0~20190531112735.39+stretch~1.gbp6131b7
Host: example.com
token: tokenisreallyhere==
debug: 1

{"OrganizationCode":10,"EventID":"5524","FunctionID":"321","Description":"Test"}HTTP/1.1 400 Missing model object in request body.  Check body And header content type.
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
ETag: ""
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2019 21:57:06 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Where do I set the body?

Comment: Body is deprecated for guzzle use form_params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the part I think is irrelevant is the answer: I did not show that I was using `json_encode()` on `$data` before passing it.  The array, not a json object string, was expected so with `$data` as an array this works correctly.

```
$response = $client->put("/api/v1/Functions/10/".$_SESSION['eventID'].'/'.$functionID, 
                    array(
                        'headers'   => array(
                            'token' => $token,  
                            'debug' => true     
                        ), 
                        'json' => $data
                  )
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use form_params body is deprecated

```
$response = $client->put("/api/v1/Functions/10/".$_SESSION['eventID'].'/'.$functionID, 
    array(
        'headers'   => array(
            'token' => $token,  
            'debug' => true,            
        ), 
        'form_params' => $data
    )
```

Comment: Thank you.  Still getting "HTTP/1.1 400 Missing model object in request body.  Check body And header content type."

Comment: Updated post with what successful cURL request from API's test pages